# Numerical Approach to Infinite Improper Integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

So I am doing a numerical project, and I decided to make a program in Python that receives a probability density function $f_X(x)$, and then the program will tell you if $$f_X(x)\geq 0 \ \ \ \forall \ \ \ x \in S_X \\ \int_{S_X} f_X(x)\ dx = 1 $$

The problem is that in probability, it is very common to encounter infinite bounds in the integral..

I saw in class very simple methods, so I was doing some research and found the *Montecarlo Method* which basically consists in:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx = \int_{-1}^{1} f \left( \frac{t}{1 - t^2} \right) \frac{1 + t^2}{(1- t^2)^2} \ dt$$

I wanted to ask if you think this method would be appropriate?
Is it optimal?

I would appreciate feedback and any help/suggestion on the matter.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: A probability density $f(x)$ is typically a continuous function and as such has to become small for large $|x|$. Therefore the direct numerical check for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ is easier than you think. Just take some large integral bounds and find out by comparing them to larger ones if the integral is close enough to $1.0$. I have not checked that variable transformation. It is however clear that for $t=\pm 1$ you evalutate $f$ at $\pm\infty$ so that's not really much of an avail.

Comment: @KurtG. I see what you are saying about my method.. it has the same inicial problem haha. I get what you say about large $|x|$ having small values of $f_X(x)$, but do you have any formula or method that I could search to get more information about it? Thanks :)

Comment: Your question -as I understood it- was how do do someting optimally in Python. I suppose you are familiar with that language and with `quad` in particular. What exactly in my comment was not clear?

Comment: Yup, I know the language and Scipy. The problem here is that I cannot use any libraries, since it would reduce every problem to just a couple of code lines. It must be done with proper numerical methods. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Don't get this. Is it part of a homework that does not allow you to use `quad` from the standard `scipy.integrate` package ? If so your question boils down to what a good method is to integrate a function numerically. Such methods exist and literature can be found through google/wikipedia. BTW : your function $f(x)$ is probably smooth as well, and even if it was not it is probably continuous, so the method of choice is [Gauss-Hermite quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature).